# Typo with "cout < myint". Why does it work?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have this code and I searched for hours why it fails to print my income

```
int const income = 0;
std::cout << "I'm sorry, your income is: " < income;
```

Until I found I missed to write `<<` but wrote `<`. Why doesn't the compiler detect this and error out? I'm not sure why comparing `cout` makes sense?

Comment: Maybe the `ostream&` is automatically cast to int? Which compiler is it?

Comment: @RedX I compiled it on GCC, clang and comeau online.

Comment: The user's income is an integral constant expression with value 0? Not much hope for economic recovery in the Eurozone any time soon, then?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

integral constant 0 is also a null pointer constant - it can be compared to the result of `ostream`'s `operator void *`. Note that it'll fail if the constant has any value but 0.

Comment: +1: This is exactly right.  Remove the `const`, and it fails to compile.

Comment: Exactly, if you change 0 to some other number compiler will give error. For 0 it is done exception, to be able to compare pointer with NULL (gcc defines NULL as integer).

Comment: This is also easy to demonstrate with `int const foo = 0; void * v = foo;` which works well only for a const int with value 0

Comment: You are right. Although I'm worried about the term "NULL pointer" / ("null pointer"?), which `0` really isn't. Most people will probably implicitly assume you meant "null pointer constant", although some people (like me) will still get confused.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Edited to "null pointer constant" - that's the term used in the standard.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: This will also fail in compilation on g++. How can you say that it compiles in GCC? Yes, but the program in ur question compiles fine on MSVS 2010.? I am using g++ 4.8.1 & it gives me so many errors when I write < instead of << by mistake. Looks like older GCC allows this, but they should give any warnings or strictly compiler errors.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Why program fails to compile If I remove const keyword? What is the reason?

Comment: @PravasiMeet please ask this in another question. It's a nice question in itself

Answer (score 0):

When I [compile this code using GCC 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/8L4z2), I see a warning:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:6: warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect
```

...though why it's a warning rather than an error, I don't know.

**EDIT:** In fact, I don't know which comma it's referring to either, because this code:

```
int const income = 0;
std::cout << "I'm sorry your income is: " < income;
```

...generates the same warning (see [here](http://ideone.com/RRMY0)).

Comment: Which is actually oddly misleading. clang++ was at least decent enough to say the result of the expression `... < ...` was unused.

Comment: Where is the comma? Does it parse the string and find "your income is:" as the right-hand operand?

Comment: No, I don't think it does - [take a look](http://ideone.com/RRMY0) at this version. I have no idea which comma it's referring to. A bizarre warning.

Comment: @litb I've asked a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5665611/27615) re: the comma operand warning.

Comment: For anyone who may be interested, it appears that this warning is produced by a bug in GCC 4.3.4. GCC 4.5.1 does not generate a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The prototypes of the < operator are like :

```
    ​bool T::operator <(const T& b) const;
```

So I guess the compiler transtype the argument as the type of this instance. 
Did you enabled all the warnings like -Wall

Answer (score 0):

It does compile with g++ 4.4.3

```
#include  <iostream>

int main (void)
{
   int const income = 0;
   std::cout << "I'm sorry, your income is: " < income;
}
```

However, when running it with -Wall (good practice!), I got a funny message:

```
:~/stack$ g++ test.cpp -o temp
:~/stack$ g++ -Wall test.cpp -o temp
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:5: warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect
```

No clue what it actually does (or tries to do)...