# assert() with message

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, assert

I saw somewhere assert used with a message in the following way:

```
assert(("message", condition));
```

This seems to work great, except that gcc throws the following warning:

```
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
```

How can I stop the warning?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665611/why-does-this-code-produce-a-warning-referring-to-the-comma-operator) related question.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use `-Wno-unused-value` to stop the warning; (the option `-Wall` includes `-Wunused-value`).

I think even better is to use another method, like

```
assert(condition && "message");
```

Comment: Nice one, I usually do assert(condition /* message */).

Comment: This sometimes gives "Conditional expression is constant" warning in Visual Studio. Any ideas on how to remove the warning without suppressing it?

Comment: @Samaursa: you probably have an issue with plain `condition`. Does the compiler also warn with just `assert(condition);`?

Comment: It does not. The interesting thing is that OP's original problem code is the solution to VS's warnings! `assert((Msg, Cond));` works without warnings on VS 2008.

Comment: `assert((<cond>) && "msg");` causes CppCheck (v1.90) to generate an "incorrectStringBooleanError" warning.

Answer (score 24):

Try:

```
#define assert__(x) for ( ; !(x) ; assert(x) )
```

use as such:

```
assert__(x) {
    printf("assertion will fail\n"); 
}
```

Will execute the block only when assert fails.

> ***IMPORTANT NOTE:*** This method will evaluate expression `x` twice, in case `x` evaluates to `false`! *(First time, when the `for` loop is checking its condition; second time, when the `assert` is evaluating the passed expression!)*

Comment: The nice thing about this is that you can omit the message if you want by using `assert__(foo);` and the semicolon will end the block.

Comment: Such implementation will not work if `(x)` returns true only once: `string("a") a; assert__(a.append("b") == "ab") { ... }`

Comment: Why `for` and not `if`?

Comment: This does not seem to work in GCC. Failing `assert` stops the program execution and `printf` is not called.

Comment: @vil It is not possible for `assert` to stop the program before `printf` because `assert` is not called until after `printf`.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to pass a formatted message, you could use the following macros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define clean_errno() (errno == 0 ? "None" : strerror(errno))
#define log_error(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] (%s:%d: errno: %s) " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, clean_errno(), ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define assertf(A, M, ...) if(!(A)) {log_error(M, ##__VA_ARGS__); assert(A); }
```

Then use it like printf:

```
// With no args
assertf(self != NULL,"[Server] Failed to create server.");

// With formatting args
assertf((self->socket = u_open(self->port)) != -1,"[Server] Failed to bind to port %i:",self->port);
// etc...
```

Output:

> [ERROR] (../src/webserver.c:180: errno: Address already in use)
>   [Server] Failed to bind to port 8080: webserver:
>   ../src/webserver.c:180: server_run: Assertion `(self->socket =
>   u_open(self->port)) != -1' failed.

Based on http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex20.html

Comment: This, unfortunately, isn't portable. C99 requires that you use at least one of the optional arguments in a variadic macro (e.g this: `assertf(x == y, "x does not equal y")` violates the standard. This is easily rectified via `assertf(x == y, "%s", "x does not equal y")` however). It also relies on the gcc extension `##__VA_ARGS__` which isn't necessarily a bad thing, but it does make it less portable

Answer (score 4):

By tradition, `(void)` communicates to the compiler that you are knowingly ignoring an expression:

```
/* picard.c, TNG S6E11. */
#define assertmsg(x, msg) assert(((void) msg, x))
assertmsg(2+2==5, "There! are! four! lights!");
```

Answer (score 2):

For unexpected default case of a switch, an options is

```
assert(!"message");
```

Comment: This seems to be always false. Where is the condition that is being tested?

Comment: This useful for unexpected default case of a switch.

Comment: That, while true, doesn't have anything to do with the original question.

Answer (score 0):

A function that takes `const char*` and returns `true` would probably save you from all sorts of warnings:

```
#include <assert.h>

int always_true(const char *msg) {
    return 1;
}

#define assert_msg(expr, msg) assert((expr) && always_true(msg))
```

Comment: Definitely not from "unused parameter" warnings.

Comment: That's easy to fix: just `(void*)msg`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed @pmg's answer to be able to control the output. The `(... && "message")` didn't work for me.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define __DEBUG__ 1

assert ((1 == 1) && 
       (__DEBUG__ && printf("  - debug: check, ok.\n")) || !__DEBUG__);
```

Comment: Try `NDEBUG` instead of `__DEBUG__`. It's the standard way to do this as defining `NDEBUG` automatically disables all `asset`s.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it this way in C. This allows calling `assert` the following ways:

```
assert(expression);
assert(expression, "reason");
assert(file, "cannot open %s", filename);
```

Here is the code:

```
#define assert(cond, ...) \
  if (!(cond)) \
    _assert(#cond, __FILE__, __LINE__, #__VA_ARGS__ __VA_OPT__(,) ##__VA_ARGS__)

void _assert (const char* snippet, const char* file, int line, const char* message, ...)
{
  print("assert failed %s:%d %s\n", file, line, snippet);
 
  if (*message)
  {
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, message);
    char* data = va_arg(arg, char*);
    vprintf(data, arg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could write your own macro that provides the same usage of `_Static_assert(expr, msg)`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/*
 * void assert_msg(bool expr, const char *msg);
 */
#if !defined(NDEBUG)
#define assert_msg(expr, msg)   do                  \
{                                                   \
        const bool  e_ = expr;                      \
                                                    \
        if (!e_) {                                  \
                fputs(msg, stderr);                 \
                fputc('\n', stderr);                \
                assert(e_);                         \
        }                                           \
} while (0)
#else
#define assert_msg(expr, msg)   do                  \
{                                                   \
                                                    \
        if (!(expr))                                \
                warn_bug(msg);                      \
} while (0)
#endif
```

I also have a macro `warn_bug()` that prints the name of the program, the file, the line, the function, the errno value and string, and a user message, even if asserts are disabled.  The reason behind it is that it won't break the program, but it will warn that a bug will probably be present.  You could just define `assert_msg` to be empty if `defined(NDEBUG)`, though.

Answer (score -11):

According to following link
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cassert/assert/

assert is expecting only expression. May be you are using some overloaded function.

According to this, only expression is allowed and thus you are getting this warning.

Comment: The inner parenthesis make it ok: `assert( ("message", condition) );` This is C: no overloading.

Comment: Don't see what relevance a C++ website has to a C question.