# Using assert() with a message

Tags: c++, c, assert

Is it possible to write a message on assert error?

For example, using `#include <assert.h>`, I can only write:

```
void foo(int a, int b) {
  assert (a != b);
}
```

However, on an error I want to see the value of `a` and `b`. How can I do that?

Comment: if (!(a != b)) cout << whatever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867834/assert-with-message

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading. The first thing that comes to mind is the `assert(a != b && "error message")` solution, which is not would you are looking at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`assert` is just a preprocessor macro, that if the condition fails calls `abort`. You can easily make your own with a simple `if` statement, and if it fails print the values and call `abort` just like `assert`:

```
void foo(int a, int b)
{
    if (a != b)
    {
        std::cerr << "My own assertion failed: a = " << a << ", b = " << b << '\n';
        abort();
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

---

However, as you are using C++ you should probably thrown an exception instead, probably [`std::logic_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error):

```
void foo(int a, int b)
{
    if (a != b)
    {
        std::istringstream is;
        is << "Argument mismatch in `foo`: a = " << a << ", b = " << b;
        throw std::logic_error(is.str());
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: for an assert i think a #ifdef DEBUG should also be used

Comment: That's true, but the correct macro is `NDEBUG`, with the inverted meaning. That said, suggesting to replace an assertion with an exception is a bad idea. One is for runtime errors that you can handle and recover from. The other is for programming errors that an inconsistent internal state, where you should dump core and abort.

Answer (score 8):

I usually simply use `assert(a != b && "This is my error message")`. This works because `char*` can be converted to bool and that it never will be false (since the address is not 0).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write your own assert macro which can break down an expression into subexpressions and print the values of each; but it requires a lot of code to support it, and the standard `assert` macro doesn't do that on any implementation I know of.

For an example of how to implement such a thing, see the [CATCH test framework](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/wiki), in particular the implementation of the `CHECK` macro.

Alternatively, you could write macros or functions like `ASSERT_EQUAL(a,b)`, giving each subexpression as a separate argument.

Or you might write your own error-handling code without `assert`

```
if (a == b) {
    throw std::runtime_error("foo: a(" + std::to_string(a) + ") must not equal b");
}
```

Comment: Marco is possible, but I don't want to use that.

Comment: @mahmood: You could probably implement it as a function, but then you'd lose the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros telling you where the assertion is in the code, and the ability to capture the expression as a string.