# right operand of comma operator has no effect std::cout

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this code produce a warning referring to the comma operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665611/why-does-this-code-produce-a-warning-referring-to-the-comma-operator)

Why i get this warning while trying to compile this example in gcc?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "str" < 0;
}
```

> warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect
>   [-Wunused-value]

Comment: Answered correctly below, but shame on gcc for a confusing error message...where's the comma?

Answer (score 2):

Because you should be using:

```
std::cout << "str" << 0;
```

instead of

```
std::cout << "str" < 0;
```

Maybe you already know this, but it's worth clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Because it's parsed as

```
(std::cout << "str") < 0;
```

and the comparison is useless.

Comment: Why the warning tells about comma operator, not comparison operator?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov compiler bug probably.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have one <
2. Why are you doing this?